# Yii2 How to save file with custom file name?

Tags: yii, yii2-advanced-app

How to save a file using a custom file name? I used `gii generator` for my website and i have a file input in my form now i want is after saving the file the name is get from `report_id` which is my `primary key`. For example, `1_.docx` the 1 is my `report_id`. I have also a `doc_name` field, Yes i can save my file and get the name in `doc_name`. For example, `sample.docx`. But my problem is when i used the `report_id` and for example save the data the name of the file is `.docx` only.

This is my controller:

```
  public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new reportDetails();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
{      
    $project= $model->doc_name;
    $model->upload_file= UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'doc_file');
    $model->upload_file->saveAs('uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension);
    $model->doc_file='uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension;
    $model->doc_name=$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension;
    $model->save();

    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success','Data saved!');
    return $this->redirect(['view','id'=> $model->report_id]);
    } 

    else {

    return $this ->render('create', [
        'model'=>$model,
    ]);
    }         

}
```

As you can see, `$project=$model->doc_name;` this the codes when i save a data, the name of the file will get from the `doc_name` but if i change it into `report_id`, when i save it the result is blank or `.docx` only.

This is my `_form`:

```
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= Html::button('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add Person', ['value' => Url::to('index.php?r=name/create'), 'class' => 'btn btn-custom-pos btn-success', 'id' => 'officialsfor']) ?>
        </br>  
        </br> 
  <?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'for_from']) ?>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
     <?= $form->field($model, 'doc_for')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
           'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Name::find()->asArray()->all(),
            'name_id',
            function($model, $defaultValue){
              return $model['position'].' '.$model['fname'].' '.$model['mname'].' '.$model['lname'];
            }),
            'language' => 'en',
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Choose a person ...'],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true,
                'width' => 500,
             ],
            ]); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'doc_from')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
           'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Name::find()->asArray()->all(),
           'name_id',
            function($model, $defaultValue){
            return $model['position'].' '.$model['fname'].' '.$model['mname'].' '.$model['lname'];
            }),
            'language' => 'en',
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Choose a person ...'],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true,
                'width' => 500,
            ],
            ]); ?>
 <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
      </div>
        </br>
        </br></br></br>
      <div class="broder" style=" border-radius: 5px; padding: 12px; ">    
      </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <?= $form->field($model, 'user_id')->textInput(['type' => 'hidden','style'=>'width:500px;','placeholder' => 'Enter a Reference No....','value' =>ucfirst(Yii::$app->user->identity->first_name) . ' ' . ucfirst(Yii::$app->user->identity->middle_name) . ' ' . ucfirst(Yii::$app->user->identity->last_name)]) ?>
       <?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'user_id', ['label'=>ucfirst(Yii::$app->user->identity->first_name) . ' ' . ucfirst(Yii::$app->user->identity->middle_name) . ' ' . ucfirst(Yii::$app->user->identity->last_name),'style' => 'font-size: 21px;','class' => 'color']) ?>
      <br>
      <br>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'reference_no')->textInput(['style'=>'width:500px','placeholder' => 'Enter a Reference No....']) ?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'subject')->textInput(['maxlength'=>true,'style'=>'width:500px','placeholder' => 'Enter a Subject....']) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'doc_date')->widget(
        DatePicker::className(), [
            'inline' => false,
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Choose a Entry Date ...'],
            'clientOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
              ]
             ]);?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top: 14px; ">
         </br>
         </br>
         </br></br>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'drawer_id')->textInput(['maxlength'=>true,'style'=>'width:500px','placeholder' => 'Enter a Drawer ID....', ]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'doc_name')->textInput(['maxlength'=>true,'style'=>'width:500px','placeholder' => 'Enter a Document Name....']) ?>
      <?= $form->field($model, 'doc_file')-> widget(
        FileInput::classname(),[
      'name' => 'doc_file',
      'options' => ['accept' => '.docx','.doc','.docs'],
      'pluginOptions' => [
          'showPreview' => false,
          'showCaption' => true,
          'showRemove' => true,
          'showUpload' => false
            ]
        ]);
      ?> 
  </div>
</div>
</br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
    <div class="form-group">
      <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Create' : '<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>&nbsp;Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success'  : 'btn btn-success','style' => 'padding:10px 60px;']) ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you said report_id is primary key, so you won't get it before save the new record in db.

as per your logic, insertion is happing with new record. so you need to updated your code like below. check it.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new reportDetails();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
    {      
        $project= $model->doc_name;
        $model->upload_file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'doc_file');
        $model->upload_file->saveAs('uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension);
        $model->doc_file='uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension;
        $model->doc_name=$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension;
        $model->save();

        // after save you will get report_id
        rename('uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension, 'uploads/'.$model->report_id.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension);
        $model->doc_file='uploads/'.$model->report_id.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension;
        $model->doc_name=$model->report_id.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension;
        $model->save();


        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success','Data saved!');
        return $this->redirect(['view','id'=> $model->report_id]);
    } 

    else {

        return $this ->render('create', [
            'model'=>$model,
        ]);
    }         

}
```

Comment: You're so amazing. Its working, Thank you very much. Thumbs up!